# Kubernetes Application Upgrade Strategy for stateful Apps

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing, stateful, kubernetes-deployment

There are many upgrade strategies such as:

- Rolling upgrade
- Blue Green
- A/B testing
- Canary

and they work for apps with shared-nothing-architecture. and some strateigies also work for a distributed clusterd app like rolling upgrade for ElasticSearch

I just need to confirm that either of those strategies doesn't apply to an app that is stateful and doesn't support clustering at data tier. ( such as only one instance of app can write to external Database [ and persistent Volume ] at a time ) ?

So I wonder that the only way to upgrade is to stop and delete the current deployment and deploy a new one , with some down time?

Comment: You're going to have to relay status and availability through a message broker like KubeMQ or similar, and use a control instance to set only the fully built and most updated single container instance as production live based on their messages (which should include build status, release version, etc)

Comment: For example your control box might subscribe to build messages and relay to your load balancer which instance to forward requests to based on the highest version number of containers that report `ready` status. Each container should publish its version number and build status as they complete build steps.

Comment: ok , I didnt get it , but for example I am running Jira Server , which support running only one pod at time , so which upgrade strategy applies to that

Comment: In the event of a stateful app, your load balancer should only allow traffic to the single instance. You may have multiple containers running jira, but only one of them should actually receive requests or be allowed to connect to other containers. Additional instances need to remain idle with no activity as optional backups if the live one fails. Your consideration for which should receive traffic is not part of the upgrade strategy, it is part of the routing strategy, which is decided by a central control authority, not kubernetes.

Answer (score 0):

In Kubernetes 1.7 and later, the StatefulSet controller supports automated updates.
There are 2 valid methods, RollingUpdate and OnDelete.

For more info check this [Official Documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/basic-stateful-set/#updating-statefulsets)